# How can I sort an Arraylist of objects using multiple criteria on one Comparator?

Tags: java, collections, comparator, sortedset

I'm trying to implement a Comparator in Java using Kotlin Collections (SortedSet). In my arraylist I have multiple objects of `Arraylist<Payment>()`. I also have a payments Hashmap with some of the payments `HashMap<String, Integer>() in getPaymentIds()`, String value is my payment id, Integer is the count

My sorting order is first all the payments contained in the Hashmap with a value greater than 1 sorted by the Integer value (count), then payments not in the Hashmap

This is what I have been playing with but the problem is it returns a Set with only one element

> ```
> public final int compare(final Payment o1, final Payment o2) {
>         boolean b2 = true;
>         if (getPaymentIds().get(o2.getId()) != null) {
>             final Integer count = getPaymentIds().get(o2.getId());
>             
>             if (Intrinsics.compare(count, 1) >= 0) {
>                 b2 = false;
>             }
>         }
>
>         boolean b = false;
>         if (getPaymentIds.get(o1.getId()) != null) {
>             final Integer value3 = getPaymentIds.get(o1.getId());
>             
>             if (Intrinsics.compare(value3, 1) < 0) {
>                 b = true;
>             }
>         }
>
>         return ComparisonsKt.compareValues(b2, b);
> ```

I have played around with this code and the closest am getting is receiving the sorted set with only one element

Comment: `Comparator.comparing(....).thenComparing(...)` would be much easier

Answer (score 0):

You can cascade in your checks. In my example, I am using a, b and c as the value fields in Payment

```
public int compareTo(Payment p1, Payment p2) {
  int diff = p2.a == null ? -1 : p2.a - p1.a == null ? -1 : p1.a; // if a is a number, than p2.a - p1.a correctly returns the order (as per compareTo's api) between them
  if (diff != 0) return diff;
  diff = p2.b == null ? -1 : p2.b - p1.b == null ? -1 : p1.b;
  if (diff != 0) return diff;
  diff = p2.c == null ? -1 : p2.c - p1.c == null ? -1 : p1.c;
  return diff; // if diff is still 0, the objects are equal, and either order is acceptable    
}
```